# Cloud computing - Azure

Tags: .net, cloud

We are looking for information on migrating existing Asp.Net 2.0 web application to cloud(Azure).

Could you please let us know if you have any documents/template/resource to kick start with?

Answer (score 1):

Note sure if you still need this info however if you are new to Windows Azure, recently Windows Azure team created a step by step Windows Azure learning Path site as below:

http://walearningpath.cloudapp.net/

You can select level 100/200/300 course per your requirement and follow your pace.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Azure Learning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsazure/dd439432) page. There are a lot of information about building `Windows Azure` apps.

[Building ASP.NET Applications with Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsazure/WAZPlatformTrainingCourse_BuildingASPNETApplicationswithWindowsAzure) - step by step guide to build `ASP.NET` applications that use the `ASP.NET Azure Providers` and explore `Windows Live` authentication in `Windows Azure`.

Answer (score 0):

[Getting started with Windows Azure](http://devexpp.blogspot.com/2010/12/getting-started-with-windows-azure.html).

Answer (score 0):

[moving asp.net to azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uscloud/archive/2012/03/22/windows-azure-for-the-asp-net-developer-series-part-1-get-ready.aspx)

This link should have all you need to move to azure.